# mysql_query() insert too much data

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
{
    if ($testArray[$i] != 0)
    {
        $sql = "insert into `dbTest`.`dbTable` (`colA`) values ('$input[$i]')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }   
}
```

If I copy the result from the browser to phpMyAdmin, the data will be inserted successfully.
But when I use the function mysql_query() to insert.
The every data will be inserted three times.
On the other hand, I have 100 data to insert, but the database will obtain 300 data.
If you faced the similar problem, would you please help.
Thanks^^

Comment: What is `$input[$i]`??And give us example of `$testArray[$i]`

Comment: Your loop does 1000 iterations. Are you sure there are only 100 non-zero elements in the array?

Comment: What does `count(array_filter($testArray))` return?

Comment: the number of non-zero element is 368.

Comment: The data of array testArray is integer.
And the data of array input is string

Comment: If there are 368 non-zero elements in the array, then your loop should insert 368 rows, not 100. I don't understand the problem

Comment: My FOR loop iteration is 1000.
The number of non-zero element is 368.
So my expected result is that insert 368 data into database.
But the final result is that insert into 1104 data into database

Comment: So you might have a problem with your `if ($testArray[$i] != 0)`.

Comment: I put a variable into the IF to count the times.
And the output is the same as the non-zero element

Comment: I tried the sizeof in my for loop.
`$count = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($testArray);$i++)
{
if ($testArray[$i] != 0)
{
    $sql = "insert into `dbTest`.`dbTable` (`colA`) values ('$testArray[$i]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $count++;
}   
}`
The $count is 368 same as my expected number.
But the data in database is 736 now

Comment: @user2778747 did you empty your db before executing this data ?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, and your code is a widely open door to SQL injection.

Comment: @glglgl ok for the deprecated part....but how can you affirm that about SQL injection? You don't know what is in `$input[$i]`

Comment: It sounds like you just run your script ... and again....and again....without deleting previous entries :)

Comment: First, I empty the database.
Second, I run the code in order to insert the 368 non-zero data.
Final, the database obtain 736 data.
The MySQL code I output to browser is right.
So I think I forget to do something in the connection between PHP and MySQL.
How to delete the previous entries?
Close the connection with MySQL after every insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sizeof` in your for loop:

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($testArray);$i++)
{
    if ($testArray[$i] != 0)
    {
        $sql = "insert into `dbTest`.`dbTable` (`colA`) values ('$testArray[$i]')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I am tempted to +1, but you do not lose any word about the SQL injection door wide open in this code...

Comment: @glglgl How can you say that ? ...you don't know what is in $testArray

Comment: @FabienTheSolution That's right, but I had the impression that it is this way. Usually, escaping is done very close to the DB functions in order to have the original data stored and not the escaped data (which would as well be memory-intensive).

Comment: @glglgl and FabienTheSOlution but the most confusing thing is why the data is getting inserted 3 times :O